# CSS3D StereoEffect creating dual non synced webpages

Tags: stereo-3d, stereoscopy

This project is a combination of a few things I've found, first embedding webpages in Three.js:

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/embedding-webpages-in-a-3d-threejs-scene.html

and the second is the custom CSS 3D Renderer I found on stackoverflow:

[Three.js StereoEffect cannot be applied to CSS3DRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913821/three-js-stereoeffect-cannot-be-applied-to-css3drenderer)

The effect is almost exactly what I wanted, except instead of simply re-drawing the output from one side to the other, it's loading two separate instances, which sorta breaks the point of going VR...

[image]

Any ideas?  Here's the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UmXmdgyhZkbeuZlCrXFUXx-yYEKtLzFP

My goal was to render the Ace cloud editor in a VR environment using the stereo effect algorithm (which seems like it could be a fun new way to develop code if you had a wireless keyboard/trackpad with a VR headset, locking the camera in one location of course but still needing the mirrored view for the lenses)...

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-Keyboard-with-Touchpad-for-iOS-Android-Smart-phone-Tablet-PC/112515393899?_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIM.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20161006002618%26meid%3D50ca4e61c27345df85a8461fb1a0e6d5%26pid%3D100694%26rk%3D7%26rkt%3D30%26sd%3D222631353709&_trksid=p2385738.c100694.m4598

https://www.walmart.com/ip/ONN-Virtual-Reality-Headset-White/187088616?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0